# Is the space of rigid Riemannian metrics convex?

Tags: differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, symmetry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Let $g_1,g_2$ be two rigid Riemannian metrics on it. (i.e with no isometries except the identity).

Is it true that every convex combination of $g_1,g_2$ is also rigid?

---

I suspect the answer is negative for some $M$. (i.e there are manifolds whose space of rigid metrics is not convex). However, I only have an idea which I am not sure how to turn into a rigorous proof:

**Idea:** Show there exists two metrics $g_1,g_2$ and a **non-rigid** metric $h$ such that $h+(g_1-g_2),h+(g_2-g_1)$ are rigid metrics (positivity is not trivial).

Then,

$[ h+(g_1-g_2)]+[h+(g_2-g_1)]=2h$ is a sum of two rigid metrics which is not rigid.

I am not sure how to show this for any particular $M$. Perhaps there is some argument which uses somehow the fact that rigidity of a metric is a "generic" property.

Comment: I feel quite strongly that this should be false for any smooth $M$ (of dim > 1 of course) that is acted on effectively by a finite group. The idea being that you take a metric for which there are isometries and patch in a metric on the unit disc that has no local isometries, in such a way that there are obviously no isometries that take this patch elsewhere (say, its scalar curavture at some point is much higher than elsewhere). Do this in such a way that you have a "positive" and "negative" version of this construction, which have the original metric as a convex combination.

Comment: (Note that the condition that $M$ is not acted on by a finite group is the same as "$M$ has a non-rigid metric").